# SQL: number of bound variables

Tags: php, sql, database, spaces

i read few topics here but i dont find right answer.

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid
parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
....
```

PHP code:

```
$sarray[':item1'.$i] = $ws->getCell($item1.$i)->getValue();
$sarray[':item2'.$i] = $ws->getCell($item2.$i)->getValue();
$sarray[':item3'.$i] = $ws->getCell($item3.$i)->getValue();

$sql = update ...

$sql1 = $DB->prepare($sql);    

$sql1->execute($sarray);
```

And after executing i am getting Error(it is at top).

**Problem:**

Problem is that, **$sarray[':item1'.$i]**  and **$sarray[':item2'.$i]** have same definition and if add third **$sarray[':item3'.$i]** it makes fault, but i dont know how to fix it.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: can you share the query you `prepare`d?

Comment: I am getting values from xlsx document and all is ok but when is 
for example $sarray[':item3'.$i] = 123 45  it makes error, i think its because space and apostrophe is missing

Comment: Sorry it not space... i now put code without spaces and same... Cant imgine where is fault